# Rxjs 5: How to establish chain of Observable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm novice to RxJS,  I'm trying to implement chain of observable that behave exactly like MS-Excel. The concept: Lets assume the excel have 5 columns 'Name', 'Age', 'Sex', 'Country', 'Zipcode'. We can apply filter on each column independently that also affect the records show in the other columns.

Here the data-source receives the data back-end service, the data-source will have only two functions "addRecord" & "removeRecord".

How I'm trying to achieve here lets say I will create Observable and attach to the data-source call it as OBS-1 this will receive data from data-source. The OBS-1 can have its own filters. Lets say I will create another Observable OBS-2 which will receive data OBS-1 (filtered data if any filters in OBS-1). Another Observable say OBS-3 which again receive data from OBS-2 (filtered if any in OBS-2), so on.

If OBS-2 is destroyed (unsubscribed) the OBS-3 will receive the data from OBS-1.

How do we achieve this in the RxJs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood a few thing about Rx. Observables do not have filters and you do not 'live' add and remove filters from them. Neither do observables forward data based on who is subscribed.

Instead, you build up a call chain. You start with a source observable, like one from the `addRecord` and one from the `removeRecord` event. You then chain these observables to form new observables trough various [operators](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#operators) in Rx and eventually you subscribe to the final observable. Subscribing will activate the entire chain and when the source events fire, all operators will trigger and eventually the event will (if not filtered) reach `subscribe`.

You can actually do the thing you describe in Rx. Changing a filter on an observable for example can be done relatively easy with `switchMap`, an operator that let you project a sequence onto another and switch over to the new sequence each time. For example `filterSource.switchMap(filterFunction => Obs-1.filter(filterFunction))`. Even simpler than this, you could just unsubscribe the first subscription and set up the Rx chain again. Using the build in functions however leaves a lot of juggling state out of the equation.

However, i strongly suspect you do not actually need behavior that is this complicated. What you want can be archived simply like this:

```
var Src-1 = fromEvent(dataSource, 'addRecord') // create the first source
var Src-2 = fromEvent(dataSource, 'removeRecord') // and the other source
var Obs-1 = Src-1.combineLatest(Src-2) // combine both sources
  .filter(e => someCondition(e)) // filter the source
var Obs-2 = Obs-1.mergeMap(e => someOtherCondition(e) ? Change(e) : Rx.Observable.of(e)) // on someOtherCondition, either transform the source with the `Change(e)` function. Or keep it unchanged with `of(e)`
var Obs-3 = Obs-2.filter(e => anotherCondition(e)) // Filter again
var sub = Obs-3.subscribe() // activate the sequence.
```

Comment: thanks for correcting me. Each observer (OBS-1, OBS-2 etc...) can have its own subscription which will be receive the data. In fact the observes will be added dynamically. How to we do this?

Comment: How do you dynamically receive observables? Don't you mean subscriptions? I think you need to be more specific in what you want and what your sources are that cause these changes. Rx is about reactive programing, and in reactive programming it's important to understand where your data comes from and not so much how you manipulate it. Once you have the source clear, the rest will fall into place, right now you seem to be looking for the wrong solution.